# Mini Nikkei Futures Contract - Tick and Point Value

Tags: equities, futures, derivatives, trading, indexes

for the Mini Nikkei Futures Contract traded at the Osaka Japanese Exchange, it states that the Tick Value is 500 Yen per Tick. But the actual contract is quoted in 5 Point Increments. Is the correct tick value 500 Yen per 1 Point, or 500 Yen per 5 Points ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

500 yen/tick = 500 yen / (5pts)

Comment: thanks, appreciate the response, thats exactly correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just for extra clarification of the Tick and Tick Value of how it is equated and calculated, the following is a description,

For this Futures Contract, 1 Tick  = 5 Points, a 1 Tick Value = 500 Yen.  A 1 Tick Move, equates to 500 Yen ( 1 Tick = 500 Yen ) .  So in other words, a 5 Point Move, equates to 500 Yen ( 5 Points = 500 Yen ) .